# Add exact same amount of horizontal spread/ "jitter" / dodge in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have measurement from three groups that I would like to plot, each with five observations.
I would like to plot all the points, however the numeric values are very close within each group. Changing alpha helps, but it is still difficult to observe the seperate points.

Thus I would like to add some horizontal spread (on theX-axis). Partial overlap of the points is ok.  geom_jitter() can achieve this, but adds a random spread, whereas I would like to spread the five points uniformly in the X-axis as there is no randomness in the data in the horizontal axis.

Geom_dotplot() could create an even spread, but to my understanding only works with discrete / binned values.

Here is  my ggplot output, and reproducible code with the data in tribble format and the ggplot code :

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~projection,               ~E.DAP, ~Shielding,
  "AP", 2.88755980861244e-06,     "None",
  "AP", 2.87626262626263e-06,     "None",
  "AP",             2.87e-06,     "None",
  "AP", 2.87702265372168e-06,     "None",
  "AP", 2.87775551102204e-06,     "None",
  "CRAN", 2.93893129770992e-06,     "None",
  "CRAN", 2.92857142857143e-06,     "None",
  "CRAN", 2.93517017828201e-06,     "None",
  "CRAN",           2.9375e-06,     "None",
  "CRAN", 2.93831168831169e-06,     "None",
  "LAO", 6.88053097345133e-06,     "None",
  "LAO", 6.90217391304348e-06,     "None",
  "LAO", 6.84489795918367e-06,     "None",
  "LAO", 6.84792626728111e-06,     "None",
  "LAO", 6.86425339366516e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CRAN", 7.11216730038023e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CRAN",  7.1039501039501e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CRAN",  7.1042471042471e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CRAN", 7.09368635437882e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CRAN", 7.10183299389002e-06,     "None",
  "RAO",             2.48e-06,     "None",
  "RAO", 2.47540983606557e-06,     "None",
  "RAO", 2.46979865771812e-06,     "None",
  "RAO", 2.46206896551724e-06,     "None",
  "RAO",         2.453125e-06,     "None",
  "RAO-CRAN", 1.87972508591065e-06,     "None",
  "RAO-CRAN", 1.87068965517241e-06,     "None",
  "RAO-CRAN", 1.88461538461538e-06,     "None",
  "RAO-CRAN", 1.86816720257235e-06,     "None",
  "RAO-CRAN",  1.8735632183908e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CAUD", 6.03324808184143e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CAUD", 6.06502242152466e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CAUD", 6.04785894206549e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CAUD",  6.0402144772118e-06,     "None",
  "LAO-CAUD", 6.02949061662198e-06,     "None",
  "RAO-CAUD", 6.30573248407643e-07,     "None",
  "RAO-CAUD", 6.29834254143646e-07,     "None",
  "RAO-CAUD", 6.35467980295566e-07,     "None",
  "RAO-CAUD", 6.38297872340426e-07,     "None",
  "RAO-CAUD", 6.37755102040816e-07,     "None",
  "CAUD", 3.81597222222222e-06,     "None",
  "CAUD", 3.83083511777302e-06,     "None",
  "CAUD",  3.8330550918197e-06,     "None",
  "CAUD", 3.82936507936508e-06,     "None",
  "CAUD", 3.81614349775785e-06,     "None",
  "AP", 4.53580901856764e-07, "Standard",
  "AP", 4.46745562130178e-07, "Standard",
  "AP",  4.4973544973545e-07, "Standard",
  "AP", 4.44976076555024e-07, "Standard",
  "AP", 4.52380952380952e-07, "Standard",
  "CRAN", 1.20574162679426e-06, "Standard",
  "CRAN", 1.20113314447592e-06, "Standard",
  "CRAN", 1.19130434782609e-06, "Standard",
  "CRAN", 1.19349593495935e-06, "Standard",
  "CRAN", 1.19757575757576e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO", 1.50961538461538e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO", 1.50761421319797e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO", 1.51209677419355e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO", 1.52216748768473e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO", 1.51476793248945e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO-CRAN", 2.96213425129088e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO-CRAN", 2.95991561181435e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO-CRAN",             2.95e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO-CRAN", 2.95744680851064e-06, "Standard",
  "LAO-CRAN", 2.95266272189349e-06, "Standard",
  "RAO", 1.51515151515152e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO", 1.52173913043478e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO", 1.52866242038217e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO", 1.57575757575758e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO", 1.59420289855072e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO-CRAN", 2.41379310344828e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO-CRAN", 2.33050847457627e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO-CRAN", 2.34741784037559e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO-CRAN", 2.33812949640288e-07, "Standard",
  "RAO-CRAN", 2.34817813765182e-07, "Standard",
  "LAO-CAUD", 1.89125295508274e-07, "Standard",
  "LAO-CAUD", 1.87110187110187e-07, "Standard",
  "LAO-CAUD", 1.89309576837416e-07, "Standard",
  "LAO-CAUD", 1.90821256038647e-07, "Standard",
  "LAO-CAUD", 1.89189189189189e-07, "Standard",
  "AP",  3.7542662116041e-08,      "XRB",
  "AP", 3.89972144846797e-08,      "XRB",
  "AP", 4.15335463258786e-08,      "XRB",
  "AP", 3.83275261324042e-08,      "XRB",
  "AP", 4.09556313993174e-08,      "XRB",
  "CRAN",                4e-08,      "XRB",
  "CRAN", 4.08163265306122e-08,      "XRB",
  "CRAN", 4.06905055487053e-08,      "XRB",
  "CRAN", 3.94574599260173e-08,      "XRB",
  "CRAN", 3.90835579514825e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO", 6.47249190938511e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO", 6.69144981412639e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO", 6.42570281124498e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO", 6.19834710743802e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO",             6.25e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CRAN", 5.31914893617021e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CRAN", 5.11247443762781e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CRAN", 5.30821917808219e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CRAN", 5.17857142857143e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CRAN", 5.31732418524871e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO", 3.30578512396694e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO", 3.38983050847458e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO", 3.33333333333333e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO", 3.07017543859649e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO",  3.2171581769437e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CRAN", 3.44827586206897e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CRAN",  3.5264483627204e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CRAN", 3.25581395348837e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CRAN", 3.43007915567282e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CRAN", 3.37837837837838e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CAUD", 5.70776255707763e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CAUD", 5.50847457627119e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CAUD", 5.51876379690949e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CAUD", 5.42797494780793e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO-CAUD", 5.53191489361702e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CAUD",  2.1505376344086e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CAUD", 1.52990264255911e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CAUD", 1.58033362598771e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CAUD", 1.47679324894515e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CAUD", 1.60213618157543e-08,      "XRB",
  "CAUD", 3.84024577572965e-08,      "XRB",
  "CAUD", 3.98671096345515e-08,      "XRB",
  "CAUD",                4e-08,      "XRB",
  "CAUD", 3.92156862745098e-08,      "XRB",
  "CAUD", 3.94574599260173e-08,      "XRB",
  "RAO-CAUD", 4.52961672473868e-08, "Standard",
  "RAO-CAUD", 4.12844036697248e-08, "Standard",
  "RAO-CAUD", 4.83870967741936e-08, "Standard",
  "RAO-CAUD", 4.29184549356223e-08, "Standard",
  "RAO-CAUD", 4.38356164383562e-08, "Standard",
  "CAUD", 8.58974358974359e-08, "Standard",
  "CAUD", 8.70646766169154e-08, "Standard",
  "CAUD", 8.66372980910426e-08, "Standard",
  "CAUD", 8.67579908675799e-08, "Standard",
  "CAUD", 8.70113493064313e-08, "Standard",
  "LAO90", 3.38266384778013e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO90", 3.34346504559271e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO90",  3.2258064516129e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO90", 3.21543408360129e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO90", 3.20987654320988e-08,      "XRB",
  "LAO90", 8.60215053763441e-08, "Standard",
  "LAO90", 8.88888888888889e-08, "Standard",
  "LAO90", 8.44686648501362e-08, "Standard",
  "LAO90", 8.90804597701149e-08, "Standard",
  "LAO90", 8.67052023121387e-08, "Standard",
  "LAO90", 1.96982378854626e-05,     "None",
  "LAO90", 1.97443820224719e-05,     "None",
  "LAO90", 1.96883720930233e-05,     "None",
  "LAO90", 1.96856540084388e-05,     "None",
  "LAO90", 1.96415770609319e-05,     "None"
)

ggplot(df , aes(x=projection, y=E.DAP, color=Shielding)) + 
  geom_jitter(size = 2.5, width=0.2, height=0, alpha =0.8) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1, size=8)) +
  labs(title= "mSv/DAP according to projection",
       y="mSv/mGy*cm2 ", x="")+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8), legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "transparent")) +  
  scale_color_manual(values=c(c("#69ac5c", "#5b86c3","#c7533b")))  +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: Shape=4 does improves the readability, but doesn't make the horizontal spread symmetric.

Answer (score 4):

Package `ggbeeswarm` could be used...
The appearance could be enhanced with a different shape or the arguments of `geom_beeswarm`: `alpha`, `dodge.width` or `groupOnX`.

Setting `dodge.width` forces the points to be grouped by the `Shielding` variable. The updated answer, nominally includes a value of 0.1, setting dodge.width closer to zero makes is seem as if there is no dodging and keeps points from the same Shielding value together. A larger dodge.width value will help distinguish points for x variables such as "CAUD".

To ensure overplotting by `Shielding` is consistent create a plotting order variable. Arbitrarily set by arranging the data by Shielding so that the last variable plots last, this could be altered to suit.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggbeeswarm)


df1 <- 
  df %>%  
  arrange(Shielding) %>% 
  mutate(plot_order = row_number())

ggplot(df1, aes(x = projection, y = E.DAP, color = Shielding, order = plot_order)) + 
  geom_beeswarm(size = 2.5, alpha = 0.9, dodge.width = 0.1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(c("#69ac5c", "#5b86c3","#c7533b")))  +
  labs(title= "mSv/DAP according to projection",
       y="mSv/mGy*cm2 ", x="")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "transparent"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1, size=8))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. ggbeeswarm helped me! However, in your solution, for instance in caud there are som blue dots, then red dots, then blue dots again which is a bit messy. I set cex=0.7, and dodge.width=0.1. This improved the plot, but for some reason in some instances the red dots came above the blue and in som instances the inverse (even if I made it an ordered factor).  To solve this issue I had to create an empty ggplot object, and then plot three seperate beeswarms using "data = df %>% filter(Shielding=="XRB") etc.  The resulting plot was then exactly as I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: Not sure it is necessary to include multiple plots, updated answer to show how this can be achieved with `geom_beeswarm` , `dodge.width` argument.

Comment: That is indeed a more elegant solution. However, if you look at both my example with geom_jitter and your answer : In LAO90 the blue dots are in front of the red dots, whereas in the next group, RAO, the blue dots are in front of the red ones, and then the blue are again in front of the red in RAO-CAUD. I find it a bit strange they are alternating which color group is in front.  Setting alpha=0.5 like you did make it less apparent, but it is still not consisten which color is in the top layer.

Comment: This can be achieved by creating a plotting order variable: see updated answer.

Comment: Yes! It works, actually it even works without adding the "order" aesthetic. Apparently ggplot stack the points according to row number (something I was not aware of), and you solution using "arrange" nicely solves the problem.  Thank you again for the answers and the updates. C

Comment: That's useful to know, Please accept the answer if it indeed does (finally) answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually calculate an offset after transforming your x into a continuous variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)

## prepare x
df <- df %>%
  group_by(projection) %>%
  mutate(
    group = cur_group_id(),
    x = rep(seq(unique(group) - .1, unique(group) + .1, 0.05), 3)
  ) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = E.DAP, color = Shielding)) +
  ## you can use geom_point now
  geom_point(alpha = 0.8) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 8)) +
  labs(title = "mSv/DAP according to projection",
    ## use x = NULL and color = NULL instead of your theme element
    y = "mSv/mGy*cm2 ", x = NULL, color = NULL
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.8), legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "transparent")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(c("#69ac5c", "#5b86c3", "#c7533b"))) +
  ## you will now need to set the breaks and labels 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq_len(max(df$group)), labels = sort(unique(df$projection)))
```

[image]